# Select Next 10 Characters Following Specific String

Tags: mysql, substr, locate

I'm trying to figure out how to create a single MySQL query that will allow me to display only the next 10 characters following the string "filter" in the Message field. The string "filter" appears at various positions in each record, so I can't use a position filter.

I've been trying to use something like like what I have below, however I've been unable to get the correct query.

```
SELECT RIGHT(Message,LOCATE('filter',Message) - 10) FROM table
```

The Message field records within the table looks like:

```
QgySSW8fwD25iQ.filter0019p3las1-31205-59C3D
6t2fJw.filter0010p3las1-9745-59
filter0025p3las1-13130-59C3D317
```

And I'm looking for them to look like this after the query:

```
0019p3las1
0010p3las1
0025p3las1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of LOCATE() within SUBSTRING(). See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6421c/4)

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`message` varchar(200))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`message`)
VALUES
    ('QgySSW8fwD25iQ.filter0019p3las1-31205-59C3D'),
    ('6t2fJw.filter0010p3las1-9745-59'),
    ('filter0025p3las1-13130-59C3D317')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
SUBSTRING(message,LOCATE('filter',Message)+6,10)
from table1
```

Note that the +6 is to offset for the length of "filter" because LOCATE finds the position of the "f" and you then need to add 6 for the other characters "ilter". Once that number is determined then just get the next 10 characters.

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6421c/4/0)**:

```
| SUBSTRING(message,LOCATE('filter',Message)+6,10) |
|--------------------------------------------------|
|                                       0019p3las1 |
|                                       0010p3las1 |
|                                       0025p3las1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b043/1).

**Result table structure**

```
Create table resulttbl ( 
    id int(6) primary key auto_increment ,
    resultFIlter varchar(1000)
);
```

**Function to split string**

```
CREATE FUNCTION strSplit(x VARCHAR(65000), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INTEGER) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(65000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE output VARCHAR(65000);
  SET output = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos)
                 , LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos - 1)) + 1)
                 , delim
                 , '');
  IF output = '' THEN SET output = null; END IF;
  RETURN output;
END;
```

**Stored procedure to split and insert into result table**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FilterTable()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INTEGER;
  DECLARE endpos INTEGER;
DECLARE fullstr VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE result VARCHAR(1000);
SET fullstr = 'QgySSW8fwD25iQ.filter0019p3las1-31205-59C3D 6t2fJw.filter0010p3las1-9745-59 filter0025p3las1-13130-59C3D317';
  SET i = 2;
  SET endpos=LENGTH(fullstr) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fullstr, 'filter', '')) ;

   delete  from resulttbl;
   REPEAT
      SET result=strSplit(fullstr, 'filter', i);

      IF result IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET result=LEFT(result,10);
       INSERT INTO resulttbl (resultFIlter)  values(result);
       END IF;
    SET i = i + 1;
   UNTIL i >= endpos 
   END REPEAT;

END ;
```

Call the procedure using the statement `CALL FilterTable()`.
Now the result of your procedure is available on the table `resulttbl`.
You can get the values from that table using `select` statement as `SELECT * from resulttbl`.

**Result**

```
id  resultFIlter
1   0019p3las1
2   0010p3las1
3   0025p3las1
```

Comment: Is this is your expected output?